# which part of shaded-pole motor is electrified?

Tags: electrical

which part of a shaded pole motor is electrified? I plan to bring it to electrical shop to try it on their GFCIs. It can trip 50% of the time during start up or off in Leviton brand of GFCIs (any theory why)? But not other brands of GFCIs.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

If you hold the laminated sheet/stator. Would you get electric shock? Would the flux induce electricity in your fingers (can you touch the cooper shading rings)?

Comment: perform some tests ..... use a voltmeter to determine if parts are electrified

Comment: where do you put the two leads?

Comment: If it's tripping GFCIs you shouldn't be touching any part of it...  You've been chasing shadows for days now...Have you actually tried to megger this between hot and frame?  I bet it fails...

Comment: What do you mean "megger this between hot and frame"? The Waterpik shaded pole motor has no ground and no metal frame. I put the motor itself on an insulating glass surface, plug it in and it always trip the Leviton GFCI, but not a Siemens GFCI. I'm figuring out why the the Leviton can do that. It seems my fridge also trips on the Leviton but not other GFCI brands. I tried 4 pcs of the Leviton. Any theory what's going on in the circuit of the Leviton?

Comment: You would megger between the hot or neutral wire and the metal frame I am looking at in the picture.  As for what a megger is, that's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

A shaded pole motor is driven by the coil (all the copper windings on one side)  the laminated plates make the magenet and the EMF for the rotor to spin, but the rotor has potential, if a gfci is trips on a motor of this type it's a bad GFCI or a leakage of the windings to ground, in my experiance the gfci has problems because shaded pole motors that spin up have not been the problem,

Comment: What causes the GFCI to trip even when the shaded pole motor has no rotor inside? Inductance tricking the sense coil? It's not ground issue because there is no ground wire and it's put on isolated glass surface, etc. Certain Leviton model can constantly trip it (once for every 2 switching on or off). Why is it a bad GFCI? It works on all other loads except it.

Comment: The coil is still creating the magnet field and there are eddy currents although not much there is power being consumed.